# Deactivate Dedicated Nvidia Card

Tags: 16.04, acpi, nvidia-prime

I realise that this question has been asked a lot, but I feel like I tried everything and I'm still stuck.

I have a Laptop with a dedicated NVIDIA gpu, and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.
I've heard that nvidia-prime doesn't work so well, and honestly I can do without the nvidia card under Ubuntu alltogether. My problem is - I can't deactivate it, so it doesn't consume all my power.

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control

```
on
```

Because of this - and the fact that my laptop uses much more energy (by huge amounts) than normal - I'm convinved that the card is running and consuming my power.

I've uninstalled all nvidia drivers, I deactivated noveau drivers in grub,  glxinfo says

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile
```

I tried the program at https://github.com/marcoDallas/acpi_call_GUI , but It just produces segfaults.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to proceed from here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a similar situation and i finally solved it today, following [this guide.](http://lenovolinux.blogspot.tw/2016/05/bumblebee-on-lenovo-t440p-nvidia-gt.html?m=1)

I didnt remove nouveau (step 3) because I think its unnecessary. I also skipped disabling gpu-manager (step 9).

I installed the 364 driver so I added this to `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf`:

```
blacklist nvidia-364
blacklist nvidia-364-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-364
```

And I also changed this line:

```
remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-uvm nvidia
```

To this:

```
remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-uvm nvidia-drm nvidia-modeset nvidia
```

I did this because on my laptop `nvidia-drm` is stopping me from removing `nvidia-modeset`, which is stopping me from removing `nvidia` module, which stops bbswitch from turning off the card. I'm not sure if this is the best solution (probably not) but it works for me so far.

I also changed `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` accordingly to 364.

If success, `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` should return `0000:01:00.0 OFF`

Hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I see, this guide is about actually *using* the NVidia GPU (the last step is about testing whether the NVidia proprietary driver is actually being used), not deactivating it. What am I missing?